# A Maven plugin which displays its own dependencies

Tags: maven-plugin

How to get the list of the dependencies of a Mojo (that I am developing), dynamically at its execution?

As far as I could see (but I might miss something, obviously), the only information that seems to be available from the Mojo is about the MavenProject on which the plugin is called.

**Clarification update:** I am looking for the data of the running Mojo, not the project which the Mojo targets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

```
@Component
private MojoExecution execution;

public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
  for (Artifact artifact : (Collection<Artifact>) execution.getMojoDescriptor().getPluginDescriptor().getArtifacts()) {
    getLog().info("Artifact: " + artifact);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the plugin artifacts directly via injection:

```
/** 
 * @parameter default-value="${plugin.artifacts}" 
 */
protected List<org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact> pluginArtifacts;
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a reference to the maven project by putting this in your plugin:

```
/**
 * @parameter expression="${project}"
 * @required
 * @readonly
 */
private MavenProject project;
```

From the project, you can get virtually everything including the project dependencies.

Comment: I am aware of the MavenProject. However, it seems to contain only the data about the project the current Mojo is running for. By opposition, I am looking for data about the Mojo which is currently executing.

Comment: My intent with that answer was to get you to find MavenProject.getPluginArtifactMap() which should get you the list of artifacts for the current execution context.

Comment: Thank you, but the list of artifacts for the current execution context was not what I was looking for.